# Getting error while using $unwind and after that group by function in mongo...?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, mongodb-query

```
{
"sku" : "sku",
"price" : 0,
"name" : "name",
"attributes" : [
    {
        "name" : "fit",
        "value" : "Regular",
        "slug" : "regular",
        "fit" : "regular"
    },
    {
        "name" : "color_family",
        "value" : "Red",
        "slug" : "red",
        "color_family" : "red"
    },
    {
        "name" : "occassion",
        "value" : "Casual",
        "slug" : "casual",
        "occassion" : "casual"
    }
]
```

},

Above is my mongo collection structure, while applying $unwind to my attribute key and after that applying group by attribute slug then getting  two times group by collection..
my query is

```
db.products_mumbai.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$attributes"},
  {$group : { _id : "$attributes.color_family", quantity : { $sum:1 } } })
```

The response is

```
{ "_id" : "red", "quantity" : 21 }
{ "_id" : null, "quantity" : 126 }
```

Comment: i don't want null value in group by....then what i have to do..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely a normal behavior.

when you $unwind an array, consider MongoDB to add as new documents as you have in your array. In your case per example, the $unwind will lead to have 3 documents:

```
{
"sku" : "sku",
"price" : 0,
"name" : "name",
"attributes" :
    {
        "name" : "fit",
        "value" : "Regular",
        "slug" : "regular",
        "fit" : "regular"
    }
},
{
"sku" : "sku",
"price" : 0,
"name" : "name",
"attributes" :
    {
        "name" : "color_family",
        "value" : "Red",
        "slug" : "red",
        "color_family" : "red"
    }
},
{
"sku" : "sku",
"price" : 0,
"name" : "name",
"attributes" :
    {
        "name" : "occassion",
        "value" : "Casual",
        "slug" : "casual",
        "occassion" : "casual"
    }
}
```

Then, you ask him to group by attributes.color_family. And as only one document has this key, you have the red for one, and null for all others.

**Edit:**
If you want to avoid `null` value, then after your `$unwind` and **before** your `$group` you have to add a `$match`:

```
{ $match : { "attributes.color_family": {$exists:true} } }
```

Comment: but i don't want null value in group by... then what i have to do??

Comment: @AsheshKhatri I've edited my answer to remove the nulls.

Comment: @AsheshKhatri if the answer suits you, please don't forget to validate the answer so further people will get the answer right.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need null in output what you can do is add an additional match to your aggregation:

```
db.products_mumbai.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$attributes"},
  {$group : { _id : "$attributes.color_family", quantity : { $sum:1 } } }),
  {$match : { _id : {$ne: null }}}
)
```

Comment: As set in my answer, I'd put the $match before the $group. I think on large sets it would have better performance.

Comment: @ConstantinGuay Yeah that's true.